# How to run git svn rebase on all branches

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm using git-svn to manage a Subversion repository using git. I usually have a large number of git branches at any one time.

I often need to update them to match the latest code in the repository, but find it a pain to run `git checkout <branch>; git svn rebase` for every branch.

Is there a simpler way of doing this than writing a script (which would need to deal with conflicts)?

**EDIT**: Since the slowest part of the process is contacting the subversion server and downloading the updates, it's faster to run `git svn rebase` on one branch and then `git svn rebase --local` on the rest.

Is there an even better way?

Comment: Interesting question that I would like to know if there is an easier way. But as far as I know there is no shortcut. Do you really work on all these branches?

Comment: I'm usually working on a number of pieces of development work at once. In addition, I like to keep up to date any branches I'm not currently working on, as otherwise I tend to find I need to do painful merges further down the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your edit has the solution on the nose:

> Since the slowest part of the process is contacting the subversion server and downloading the updates, it's faster to run git svn rebase on one branch and then git rebase git-svn on the rest.

I also work with a lot of local git branches for my git-svn repositories, and find myself rebasing them daily to keep them as close to the remote branch as possible.  Using a single tracking branch to track the remote branch, and then rebasing/merging each branch from that seems to be the most efficient means of managing this particular situation from my own limited experience.

Comment: Very true. There's really no way you could rebase them all at once unless they would all rebase without conflicts. You pretty much have to do the rebases serially.